# Create Read trait object from u8 slice

Tags: rust, slice, trait-objects

I'm trying to create a `Read` trait object from a `u8` slice, to use in `murmur3` crate, like this

```
fn main() {
    let mut arr: [u8; 4] = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    let mut slice: &mut [u8] = &mut arr;
    let mut read: &mut std::io::Read = &mut slice;
}
```

But I get

```
<anon>:4:42: 4:53 error: the trait `std::io::Read` is not implemented for the type `[u8]` [E0277]
<anon>:4     let mut read : & mut std::io::Read = & mut slice;
                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~
<anon>:4:42: 4:53 help: see the detailed explanation for E0277
<anon>:4:42: 4:53 help: the following implementations were found:
<anon>:4:42: 4:53 help:   <&'a [u8] as std::io::Read>
<anon>:4:42: 4:53 note: required for the cast to the object type `std::io::Read`
error: aborting due to previous error
```

What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the error message tells you, there's a `Read` impl for `&[u8]`. There's no reason to have a `Read` impl for `&mut[u8]`, so you can just remove some of the `mut`'s in your code:

```
// no need for `mut arr`, because `Read` does not modify memory
let arr: [u8; 4] = [1, 2, 3, 4];
// `slice` needs to be `mut`, because `Read` will
// actually make the slice smaller with every step
let mut slice: &[u8] = &arr;
let mut read: &mut std::io::Read = &mut slice;
```

Comment: Thanks! But error message is just strange then. Compiler says "the trait `std::io::Read` is not implemented for the type `[u8]`" when it's actually not implemented for `& mut [u8]`

Comment: @MikhailCheshkov That's probably because there is a blanked `Read` implementation for `&mut T` where `T: Read`.